# std::max - expected an identifier

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem with `std::max`. I can't figure it out.

```
int border = 35;
int myInt = 2;
int myOtherInt = 3;
int z = std::max(myInt + 2 * border, myOtherInt + 2 * border);
```

I've included the algorithm standard header. When I mouse over max, I am getting:

> Error: expected an identifier

And a compile errors of:

> error C2589: `'('` : illegal token on right side of `'::'`
>   error C2059: syntax error : `'::'`

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you included `<algorithm>`?  Are you including `<windows.h>`?

Comment: OP sez: "I've included the algorithm standard header."

Comment: Can you include a full example we can try to compile? Your program is short enough for that.

Comment: Unrelated, but it seems like it'd be shorter and easier to read if you wrote `std::max(myInt, myOtherInt) + 2 * border;`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Hazarding a guess, since you're using VC++ – put this before any `#include`s:

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

`windows.h` defines macros named `min` and `max` like so:

```
#define min(a,b)            (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

The Windows SDK has contained these macros since before C++ was standardized, but because they obviously play havoc with the C++ standard library, one can define the `NOMINMAX` macro to prevent them from being defined.

As a rule, if you're using C++ (as opposed to C) and including `windows.h`, *always* define `NOMINMAX` first.

Comment: It looks like it compiles when I add this. But why? Is this a bug?

Comment: @Jay: apparently it's `<windows.h>` itself that messes everything up by defining macros named `min` and `max`. Congrats to Microsoft! More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913922/possible-problems-with-nominmax-on-visual-c/4914108#4914108).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The way I understand it, Windows.h defines those macros. And then somewhere in the C++ standard library, in the namespace std, the function template <class T> T max(const T& x, const T& y) is defined. So when it comes to this line, there is confusion over the max macro and the generic function max. The only odd thing is if I don't include Windows.h (so the conflict shouldn't occur) I still can't use std::max.

Comment: Maybe other standard headers include Windows.h because none of my header files are!

Comment: @Jay : If you're using MFC, or any other GUI framework, then `windows.h` will invariably be included somewhere.

Answer (score 24):

If you're on VC++, you can either use `#define NOMINMAX` prior to including any headers, or do `(std::max)(myInt + 2 * border, myOtherInt + 2 * border)`

Comment: Wow this is awesome! Just what I was looking for. I was trying to use `std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()` and the stupid windows.h was causing the preprocessor to insert std::max() in place of `max()`. Simply doing `(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max)()` is enough to throw off the preprocessor from doing the wrong thing. I didn't want to do the NOMINMAX thing because I worry windows.h might get included before it is defined, not to mention a lot of my own files include windows.h. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I would say that either `max` is `#define`'s to something else or you need to explicitly invoke the template via `std::max<int>`.

Answer (score 2):

The "using" declaration (see [using Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/was37tzw.aspx)) is yet another way to work around the issue:

```
int border = 35;
int myInt = 2;
int myOtherInt = 3;
using std::max;
int z = max(myInt + 2 * border, myOtherInt + 2 * border);
```

It allows using std::max without explicit qualification.

Answer (score 1):

Just a brief collection of other answers.

If `max(a,b)` is already `#define`d, (by including windows.h or some Windows-related project, etc.)

1. `#define NOMINMAX`
2. `#undef max`
3. `(std::max)` - Use parentheses to prevent function-like macro<sup>1)</sup>
4. `std::max<int>` - Explicitly give a type for the template.

*Precaution*: If some part of the project depends on the min/max macro, e.g. using MFC, then just simply doing `#define NOMINMAX` can cause some problem.

Maybe `#undef NOMINMAX` should be needed, e.g.:

```
// just an example
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
#undef NOMINMAX
// ...
```

(For more info, please take a look at the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4913922/10027592).)

---

<sup>1)</sup> Function-like macros only expand when the next thing after is an opening parenthesis. When surrounding the name with parentheses, the next thing after the name is a closing parenthesis, so no expansion occurs. [[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23022366/10027592)]

Comment: _"Just a brief collection of other answers"_... why? This doesn't add any value imho

Comment: @JHBonarius Please read until the end. I mentioned the precaution :) Also, there are lots of SO answers that puts together diverse answers and some people find it's helpful. I apologize if this answer consumed your precious time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `::std::max` instead? If this doesn't work, something is messing with your std namespace.