# Why do parens prevent macro substitution?

Tags: c++, stl

While researching solutions to the windows `min`/`max` macro problem, I found an answer that I really like but I do not understand why it works.  Is there something within the C++ specification that says that macro substitution doesn't occur within parens?  If so where is that?  Is this just a side effect of something else or is the language designed to work that way?  If I use extra parens the `max` macro doesn't cause a problem:

```
(std::numeric_limits<int>::max)()
```

I'm working in a large scale MFC project, and there are some windows libraries that use those macros so I'd prefer not to use the `#undef` trick.

My other question is this.  Does `#undef max` within a .cpp file only affect the file that it is used within, or would it undefine `max` for other compilation units?

Comment: `#undef X` only removes the definition of `X` until the end of the compilation of the current file (or until `X` is #define'd again, of course).

Comment: You could try `#define NOMINMAX` before including Windows.h to disable those macros.  Not sufe it that interferes with anything MFC expects to be available.

Comment: NOMINMAX will not work.  There are other libs and headers that require min and max.  In my case, it is an existing project so I don't want to be undefining things that are used by other parts of the project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function-like macros only expand when the next thing after is an opening parenthesis. When surrounding the name with parentheses, the next thing after the name is a closing parenthesis, so no expansion occurs.

From C++11 § 16.3 [cpp.replace]/10:

> Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name followed by a **(** as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the deﬁnition (an invocation of the macro).

To answer the other question, preprocessing happens before normal compilation and linking, so doing an `#undef` in an implementation file will only affect that file. In a header, it affects every file that includes that header.