# FBX Converter - Gear VR

Tags: visual-studio-2012, fbx, oculus

*This is a x-post from my question listed at https://answers.oculus.com/questions/583/fbx-converter-gear-vr.html*

I'm *attempting* to use the Oculus FBX converter tool which came bundled with the Oculus Mobile SDK for Samsung Note 4 download.

Unfortunately, FBX Converter appears to be a Windows only tool :(, so I'm attempting to run this via Parallels Desktop.

There's a readme file in the tools dir which contains some instructions for downloading the AutoDesk FBX SDK and moving to an appropriate directory. I've followed them.

Inside the tools dir I see a makefile. Windows does make? Cool, so I attempt to make:

```
makefile(3) : fatal error U1033: syntax error : '=' unexpected Stop.
```

Huh... luckily there's a Visual Studio solution here. So I open the .sln and build. Dang, looks like I have to change the Platform Toolset to v110 because I have VS2012. Try again... Ahhh man, bunch of syntax errors about unexpected identifiers in `std::max`. I guess I'll try and fix it - [std::max - expected an identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035023/stdmax-expected-an-identifier)

Cool, build is starting and..... ugh. `cannot open file libfbxsdk.lib`. Wait a second, I bet it's an issue with how the .sln is pulling in it's dependencies. Yup, wrong pathing. Add an extra `../` and here we go.... nope, no dice. `cannot open include file fbxsdk.h`.

So that's where I am right now. All I really want to do is convert an fbx file to a .ovrscene. Is that so much to ask? Is there a better way to do this? I hope so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh.... looks like there's a bin dir with the FBXConvert .exe included in the download. You'll have to add a .dll, to your System32 directory. That was awesome.