# #include <gdiplus.h> causes error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When I include `gdiplus.h` in a program that compiles well the first(there are many) error I get is:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\GdiplusImaging.h(77): error C2504: 'IUnknown' : base class undefined
```

Part of GdiplusImaging.h:

```
IImageBytes : public IUnknown  <<< error!
{
public:
     ...
```

Why it is so? Where is this IUnknown class? And why it's not in GdiplusImaging.h?

My system is Windows7 x64. VisualStudio 2010.

Including part:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib, "gdiplus.lib")
```

Comment: Do you have `windows.h` included before `gdiplus.h`?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Something's whacked with your config.

Comment: Reinstalling sdk now, something wrong with it I think

Comment: If reinstalling the sdk doesn't solve the problem, try setting "Show Includes" (under C/C++ -> advanced) to `Yes`, and recompile. You'll see the order of includes in the output window. Could make things clearer.

Comment: thanks for the tip, simple including of Unknwn.h saved my soul

Answer (score 35, accepted):

These are the standard includes for using GDI+:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
```

Comment: I used this exact block, but still had issues with min/max macros being undefined in gdiplustype.h file (that is included internally by gdiplus.h). Following thread helped -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913922/possible-problems-with-nominmax-on-visual-c

Comment: This doesn't work under VS2017 if you try to build it for platform toolset as `Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)`. Here's [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014731/gdi-library-causes-error-c2760-syntax-error-unexpected-token-identifier-e). Did anyone figure out how to build these GDI+ libraries?

Answer (score 7):

You should try to add `windows.h` and `Unknwn.h` header before `gdiplus.h`

```
#include <Unknwn.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
```

Comment: Have you try to force adding the `Unknwn.h` header before calling `gdiplus.h` ?

Comment: I wonder WHY not to include it in gdi headers?? It helped! thanks. Add it to the answer.