# GDI+ library causes "error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'" in VS2017 when compiled for XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, gdi+

I'm trying to include the following definitions for GDI+ into my Win32 C++ project that is compiled under Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <objidl.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")
```

I need to compile this project to support Windows XP. So in the project properies I selected: `Platform Toolset` as `Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)`:

[image]

But when I compile it the GDI+ library gives me this:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\objbase.h(239): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\gdiplusheaders.h(891): error C4596: 'EmfToWmfBits': illegal qualified name in member declaration
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1a\include\gdiplusstringformat.h(220): error C4596: 'GetTrimming': illegal qualified name in member declaration
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: This is extremely frustrating. Does anyone even use that GDI+ now? I [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305614/include-gdiplus-h-causes-error), but none of it works if I try to build for `Windows XP (v141_xp)`. I'm still getting the same compiler errors as I've shown above.

Answer (score 10):

Add this line before the very first(!) `#include` of COM-related header to fix `objbase.h(239): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'` :

```
typedef struct IUnknown IUnknown;
```

This fix works, because  the line in `objbase.h(239)` mentioned in the error contains `static_cast<IUnknown*>(*pp);` despite that IUnknown still haven't been declared in that place.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda got it to compile, but this is definitely not a good solution. I'm posting it here as a temp workaround until Microsoft gets their heads out of their ___es. Also if anyone finds a better way, please let me know.

I basically had to downgrade the entire project to `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)` just to compile one badly written library:

[image]

This created a problem of its own with the `std` libraries:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cstdio(50): error C4995: 'sprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cstdio(53): error C4995: 'vsprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cstring(20): error C4995: 'strcat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cstring(21): error C4995: 'strcpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cwchar(29): error C4995: 'swprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cwchar(30): error C4995: 'vswprintf': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cwchar(32): error C4995: 'wcscat': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\cwchar(34): error C4995: 'wcscpy': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
```

So I had to shunt those errors of unsafe functions:

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: 4995 )
#include <stdio.h>
#include <new>
#include <string>
#pragma warning( pop )
```

Which is far from ideal!

(You're basically sacrificing security of the app just to compile that damn GDI+ library.)

Comment: Tried `#define GDIPVER 0x0100`?

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to get this to work if you're prepared to edit the Windows header files.

In `objbase.h`, comment out line 239 or change it to:

```
static_assert (std::is_base_of <IUnknown *, *pp>::value, "pp must derive from IUnknown");
```

In `gdiplusheaders.h`, line 891, remove the redundant qualifier (`Metafile::`).

In `gdiplusstringformat.h`, line 220, remove the redundant qualifier (`StringFormat::`).

Hopefully, that will fix things for you without breaking anything.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that it may come to this.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is old, just adding what worked for me.

In my case including windows.h and compiling with VS2017 v141_xp toolset was causing me error: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'.

This resolved my issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417992/how-to-compile-code-for-windows-xp-in-visual-studio-2017)