# gdiplus header causing problems

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I just created a new Windows project in MS VC++.

I simply added the header gdiplus.h. So, my headers look like so:

#include "framework.h"

#include "BezierCurveTest.h"
#include <gdiplus.h>

For some reason, I am now getting all these weird errors like so:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

Error (active) E0020 identifier "IStream" is undefined BezierCurveTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\gdiplusbitmap.h 50

Error (active) E0020 identifier "IStream" is undefined BezierCurveTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\gdiplusbitmap.h 85

Error (active) E0020 identifier "Status" is undefined BezierCurveTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\gdiplusbitmap.h 124

Error (active) E0020 identifier "Status" is undefined BezierCurveTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\gdiplusbitmap.h 137

Error (active) E0020 identifier "Status" is undefined BezierCurveTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\gdiplusbitmap.h 150

Error (active) E0020 identifier "IStream" is undefined BezierCurveTest C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\um\gdiplusbitmap.h 152

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you.

I tried googling the error messages, but it was to no avail.

Comment: what is `gdiplusbitmap.h` ? Its either broken, or not meant to be included directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305614/include-gdiplus-h-causes-error

Comment: Edit framework.h and delete `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`.  GDI+ is mean but not lean.