# What is "minmax.h" in C++?

Tags: c++, minmax

I've been using `#include <minmax.h>` in my scripts and using `min()` and `max()` as expected. I showed this to someone and they had never seen it before, said it wasn't working for them and asked me why I wasn't including `<algorithm>` and calling `std::min()` or `std::max()`.

So my question is basically, why aren't I? I found this in a book on C++: "C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing". Googling `"minmax.h"`, I find a reference to that very book in the top result, so that even more so makes me think it's something abnormal.

Is anyone able to tell me what this is?

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that a Windows API header used to `#define min` and `max`, causing tons of headaches trying to use both standard C++ and Windows API.

Comment: Did you also have to provide that header? If so, where did you get it from? If not, what platform are you on?

Comment: I found [this](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cvs/cvs-39/cvs/lib/minmax.h.auto.html) maybe that's what you are using

Comment: The second edition of the book does not do `#include <minmax.h>`. It seems to use the standard `<algorithm>` algorithms. Edit: Yes it does, but searching for `minmax.h` failed. When searching for `minmax` I found it.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I did not, I just wrote #include <minmix.h> and it seems to work, I've checked my code to be sure and also checked if some code was supplied in the book but nope, just the #include <minmax.h> parts. I'm on windows using Visual Studios

Answer (score 8):

The C++ programming language is accompanied by the [C++ Standard Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header). There is no `<minmax.h>` header in the C++ Standard Library. No header in the standard-library has the *.h* extension. Furthermore, the header is not part of the ported C standard library either, as those headers have the *c* prefix, like `<cmath>` (which replaces the C standard-library `<math.h>` header), `<ctime>`(which replaces the `<time.h>` header) when used from the C++ Standard Library.

The [std::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and [std::max](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) functions are declared inside the [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header.

<sup>That being said, there indeed appears to be some MS header called `<minmax.h>` inside the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt` folder which defines `min` and `max` macros, not functions. But, that is some implementation specific header, and you should be using the standard `<algorithm>` header instead.</sup>

Comment: Note:: C standard library headers only have the `c` prefix when they are accessed from C++.

Answer (score 3):

> why aren't I?

People do all sort of odd things that they heard about somewhere once, be it in school or that came up as some "solution" that fixed their immediate need (usually under timeline pressure). They then keep doing things the same way because they "work". But I'm glad you stopped for a minute to ask. Hopefully we'll steer you back onto the portable C++ route :)

No, there's no need to use the non-standard `minmax.h` header. On Windows you need to define the `NOMINMAX` macro *before* you include any headers whatsoever, and include `<algorithm>` right after this macro definition. This is just to free the `min` and `max` symbols from being taken over by ill-conceived WINAPI macros. In C++, `std::min` etc. are in the `<algorithm>` header and that's what you ought to be using. Thus, the following is portable:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <algorithm>
// other includes
#undef NOMINMAX

// your code here
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27522205/1329652) for details for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

#### An ancient reference w.r.t. C++, using ancient compilers, supplying examples using non-standard C++ (e.g. headers such as `minmax.h`)

Note that the book you are mentioning, *C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing* (M.S. Joshi), [was first released in 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_S._Joshi), with a subsequent second edition released in 2008. As can be seen in the extract below, the examples in the book relied on successful compilation on ancient compiler versions (not so ancient back in 2004, but still far from recent versions).

Appendix D of the book even specifically mentions that the code examples covered by the book may not be standard-compliant, followed by the pragmatic advice that *"[...] fixing the problems should not be hard"* [**emphasis** mine]:

> The code has been tested under three compilers: **MingW 2.95, Borland 5.5, and Visual C++ 6.0**. The first two of these are available for free so you should have no trouble finding a compiler that the code works for. In addition, MingW is the Windows port of the GNU compiler, gcc, so the code should work with that compiler too. Visual C++ is not free but is popular in the City and the introductory version is not very expensive. In addition, I have strived to use only ANSI/ISO code so the code should work under any compiler. In any case, it does not use any cutting-edge language features **so if it is not compatible with your compiler, fixing the problems should not be hard.**

The compiler releases listed above are *very* old:

- [Borland 5.5 was released in 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B),
- [Visual C++ 6.0 was released in 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#6.0_(1998)),
- [GCC 2.95 was released in 1999](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-2.95/).

Much like any other ancient compiler it is not surprising that these compilers supplied non-standard headers such as `minmax.h`, particularly as it seems to have been a somewhat common *non-standard* convention, based on e.g. the following references.

- [Gnulib Module List - Extra functions based on ANSI C 89](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/MODULES.html): [`minmax.h`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gnulib.git;a=blob_plain;f=lib/minmax.h), possibly accessible in GCC 2.95,
- [Known problems in using the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler, version 6.0](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/imprint_downloads/informit/downloads/9780201703535/msbugs.html):

  > The MS library does not define the min and max algorithms, which should be found in  The workaround we use is to define a new header file, say minmax.h, which we include in any file that uses these functions: [...]
- [What is the worst real-world macros/pre-processor abuse you've ever come across?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/653686):

  > Real-world? MSVC has macros in minmax.h, called max and min, which cause a compiler error every time I intend to use the standard std::numeric_limits::max() function.

#### Alternative references for the C++ *language*

Based on the passage above, the book should most likely be considered primarily a reference for its main domain, quant finance, and not such much for C++, other than the latter being a tool used to cover the former.

For references that are focusing on the C++ language and not its application in a particular applied domain (with emphasis on the latter), consider having a look at:

- [StackOverfow C++ FAQ: The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Comment: Wow, must be an old book; VS6 _predates C++_ as we currently understand the term.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Indeed. Afaics the first edition of the book is from 2004, and I would guess the second edition from 2008 just did minor brush-ups (arguably and likely not so much to the non-standard compliant examples).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It's from 2008 I believe but the author confesses in a chapter that the majority was written in 2003. I hope I haven't learned anything terribly non-standard, it's a pretty well regarded book (within quantitative finance at least, among C++ aficionados I don't know)

Comment: @Oscar The author seems to have been a renowned professor in quant finance, specifically, so if you are aiming to learn that domain, it may be a suitable reference. As with many domain-specific references, the programming language used therein may not be the ideal reference to the language itself, and rather a tool to cover the domain (quant finance). If you are leaning towards actually learning C++ (and not solely this particular domain), consider having a look at [SO C++ FAQ: The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).

Comment: @dfri Thank you! I will give that list a look over

Comment: Wow. GCC2. I don't even have to support any projects compiled with GCC2.