# Popular header that misused function-like macro max

Tags: c++, macros

On page 1057 of *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++, Second Edition*, Bjarne Stroustrup discusses a problem with Function-like macros.

He starts with an example. The macro below:

`#define MAX(x, y) ((x)>=(y)?(x):(y))`

used in the following line:

`double dd = MAX(aa++, 2);`

substitutes to become:

`double dd = ((aa++)>=(2)?(a++):(2));`

About this example, he explains:

> On the other hand, not all the parentheses in the world could save the
> second expansion. The macro parameter `x` was given the value
> `aa++`, and since `x` is used twice in `MAX`, `a` can
> get incremented twice. Don't pass an argument with a side effect to a
> macro.
>
> As it happens, some genius did define a macro like that and stuck it
> in a popular header file. Unfortunately, he also called it `max`,
> rather than `MAX`, so when the C++ standard header defines
>
> `template<class T> inline T max(T a, T b) {return a<b?b:a;}`
>
> the `max` gets expanded with the arguments `T a` and `T b`
> and the compilers sees
>
> `template<class T> inline T ((T a)>=(T b)?(T a):(T b)) {return a<b?b:a;}`
>
> The compiler error messages are "interesting" and not very helpful. In
> an emergency, you can "undefine" a macro:
>
> `#undef max`.

Bjarne Stroustrup's story sounds like it would be a well-known one in the C++ community, however, I couldn't find anything more written about it online. Bjarne Stroustrup's frustration here suggests that this particular header created backwards compatibility problems developing C++.

What was the header Bjarne refers to in his story?

Comment: Likely Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/max

Comment: The old [`minmax.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62394972/what-is-minmax-h-in-c) header is still present in the latest Windows UCRT (though it's not used/included in any of the other headers). Yet older Windows SDKs had a dedicated [`NOMINMAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913922/possible-problems-with-nominmax-on-visual-c) macro to sanitize `windows.h`. In fairness, these are cases I happen to be familiar with, certainly not the only ones, and not necessarily what the book was referring to.