# How do I build the SOCI library without errors?

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, cmake, soci

I am having difficulties building the SOCI library.

Relevant software:

- Boost ver 1.73.0
- CMake ver 3.16
- MSVC compiler ver 19.26.28805.0
- MySQL ver 5.7
- SOCI ver 4.0.0

Relevant paths:

- Path to Boost is `E:\cpp\Lib\boost\boost_1_73_0`.
- Path to CMake is `E:\Apps\CMake\share\cmake-3.16`.
- Path to MySQL server is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\`.
- Path to MSVC is `C:\Apps\32\Microsoft\Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hostx64\x64`.

Command to build SOCI is `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debut -DSOCI_CXX11=ON -DSOCI_SHARED=ON -DWITH_BOOST=ON -DWITH_MYSQL=ON ..`

Here is the modified `Boost.cmake` file, found at `%SOCI%\cmake\dependencies\`. Comments beginning `##` explain changes.

```
## commented
#set(Boost_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)

set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
## commented
#find_package(Boost 1.33.1 COMPONENTS date_time)

## BEGIN inserted
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "E:/cpp/Lib/boost/boost_1_73_0")
message(STATUS "<< set CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH >> " ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH})

set(BOOST_ROOT E:/cpp/Lib/boost/boost_1_73_0)
message(STATUS "<< set BOOST_ROOT >> " ${BOOST_ROOT})

message(STATUS "<< FIND_PACKAGE >>")
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)

message(STATUS "<< FIND_PACKAGE COMPONENTS >>")
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS date_time)

message(STATUS "<< Boost_FOUND >> " ${Boost_FOUND})

message(STATUS "<< Boost_DATE_TIME_FOUND >> " ${Boost_DATE_TIME_FOUND})
## END inserted

## commented
#if (NOT Boost_DATE_TIME_FOUND)
#  find_package(Boost 1.33.1)
#endif()

set(Boost_RELEASE_VERSION
  "${Boost_MAJOR_VERSION}.${Boost_MINOR_VERSION}.${Boost_SUBMINOR_VERSION}")

boost_external_report(Boost RELEASE_VERSION INCLUDE_DIR LIBRARIES)
```

Here is the relevant output. Full output available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/misc/master/soci/cmake_full_output).

```
-- Boost:
-- << set CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH >> E:/cpp/Lib/boost/boost_1_73_0
-- << set BOOST_ROOT >> E:/cpp/Lib/boost/boost_1_73_0
-- << FIND_PACKAGE >>
-- << FIND_PACKAGE COMPONENTS >>
CMake Warning at E:/Apps/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1161 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  E:/Apps/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1283 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  E:/Apps/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1921 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/dependencies/Boost.cmake:18 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  cmake/SociDependencies.cmake:79 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:83 (include)


-- Could NOT find Boost (missing: date_time) (found version "1.73.0")
-- << Boost_FOUND >> FALSE
-- << Boost_DATE_TIME_FOUND >> 0
-- WARNING: Boost libraries not found, some features will be disabled.
```

Executing `msbuild.exe SOCI.sln` produces output available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/misc/master/soci/msbuild_output).

Can anyone tell me why SOCI will not build correctly? Why is it not finding the `date_time` component when it is most certainly there?

Comment: What version of Boost libraries have you built? Did you build them for Visual Studio 2019? Did you build static or shared libraries, or both?

Comment: `warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'` seems to mean its using the min macro from windows.h instead of `std::min` related [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416418/define-nominmax-using-stdmin-max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416418/define-nominmax-using-stdmin-max)

Comment: @squareskittles While in `E:\cpp\Lib\boost\boost_1_73_0`, I used the commands `bootstrap.bat` then `b2 install --prefix=E:\cpp\Lib\boost\boost_1_73_0\build`.

Comment: This doesn't specify the compiler, so it doesn't guarantee they built with Visual Studio 2019. It might be easier if you provide the *name* of one of the built libraries in your question post.

Comment: The output after running the command `b2 install --prefix=E:\cpp\Lib\boost\1_73 --build-dir=E:\cpp\Lib\boost\build --build-type=complete` is available, here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/misc/master/boost/b2_output. Unfortunately, the first part got cut off.

Comment: Re-ran the `b2` command inside `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019`. Command output file has been updated. Now shows the full output. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ptrongithub/misc/master/boost/b2_output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, most of the errors I was getting was from the included unit tests. Why? I do not know. However, if I ignore the errors and move on, everything seems to work fine.