# Qt Data Visualization fails to complie

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, compiler-errors, qt6

I am trying to use Qt Data Visualization on MSVC2019 Qt 6.2.2 inside Visual Studio 2022 project. But just including `#include <QtDataVisualization/Q3DSurface>` already leads to compile failure with tons of nonsensical error messages:

```
1>surfacegraph.cpp
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qabstract3daxis.h(88,11): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min' (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qabstract3daxis.h(88,11): error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qabstract3daxis.h(88,11): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding ':'; skipping apparent function body (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qabstract3daxis.h(91,11): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max' (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qabstract3daxis.h(129,2): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before ';' (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qabstract3daxis.h(129,2): error C2059: syntax error: ')' (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qabstract3daxis.h(129,2): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';' (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtDataVisualization\qvalue3daxis.h(41,1): error C2504: 'QAbstract3DAxis': base class undefined (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(111,2): error C3412: 'QAbstract3DAxis::QTypeInfo<QAbstract3DAxis::QGenericMatrix<N,M,T>>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(114,44): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(114,44): error C2838: '{ctor}': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(120,47): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(120,47): error C2838: '{ctor}': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(128,53): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '()' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(128,53): error C2838: '()': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(135,47): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '()' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(135,47): error C2838: '()': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(142,52): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'isIdentity' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(142,52): error C2838: 'isIdentity': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(159,52): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setToIdentity' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(159,52): error C2838: 'setToIdentity': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(172,52): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'fill' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(172,52): error C2838: 'fill': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(180,71): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'transposed' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(180,71): error C2838: 'transposed': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(190,72): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '+=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(190,72): error C2838: '+=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(199,72): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '-=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(199,72): error C2838: '-=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(208,72): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '*=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(208,72): error C2838: '*=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(220,52): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '==' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(220,52): error C2838: '==': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(231,52): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '!=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(231,52): error C2838: '!=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(239,72): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '/=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(239,72): error C2838: '/=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(249,1): error C2804: binary 'operator +' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(259,1): error C2804: binary 'operator -' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(269,1): error C2804: binary 'operator *' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(294,1): error C2804: binary 'operator *' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(304,1): error C2804: binary 'operator *' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(314,1): error C2804: binary 'operator /' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(323,52): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'copyDataTo' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(323,52): error C2838: 'copyDataTo': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(344,1): error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(364,1): error C2804: binary 'operator <<' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(373,1): error C2804: binary 'operator >>' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(388,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix2x2>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(389,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix2x3>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(390,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix2x4>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(391,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix3x2>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(392,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix3x3>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(393,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix3x4>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(394,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix4x2>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(395,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix4x3>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(172,50): error C3412: 'QTypeInfo<QAbstract3DAxis::QQuaternion>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(174,21): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(174,21): error C2838: '{ctor}': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(176,21): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(176,21): error C2838: '{ctor}': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(181,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'isNull' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(181,26): error C2838: 'isNull': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(186,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'isIdentity' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(186,26): error C2838: 'isIdentity': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(192,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'x' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(192,27): error C2838: 'x': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(193,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'y' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(193,27): error C2838: 'y': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(194,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'z' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(194,27): error C2838: 'z': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(195,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'scalar' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(195,27): error C2838: 'scalar': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(197,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setX' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(197,26): error C2838: 'setX': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(198,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setY' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(198,26): error C2838: 'setY': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(199,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setZ' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(199,26): error C2838: 'setZ': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(200,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setScalar' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(200,26): error C2838: 'setScalar': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(202,37): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'dotProduct' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(202,37): error C2838: 'dotProduct': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(207,33): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'inverted' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(207,33): error C2838: 'inverted': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(220,33): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'conjugated' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(220,33): error C2838: 'conjugated': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(225,34): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '+=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(225,34): error C2838: '+=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\main.cpp)
<SKIPPING SOME ERRORS>
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(389,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix2x3>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(390,1): error C3412: 'QetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix2x4>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(391,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix3x2>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(392,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix3x3>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(393,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix3x4>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(394,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix4x2>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qgenericmatrix.h(395,1): error C3412: 'QMetaTypeId<QAbstract3DAxis::QMatrix4x3>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(172,50): error C3412: 'QTypeInfo<QAbstract3DAxis::QQuaternion>': cannot specialize template in current scope (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(174,21): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(174,21): error C2838: '{ctor}': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(176,21): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '{ctor}' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(176,21): error C2838: '{ctor}': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(181,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'isNull' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(181,26): error C2838: 'isNull': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(186,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'isIdentity' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(186,26): error C2838: 'isIdentity': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(192,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'x' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(192,27): error C2838: 'x': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(193,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'y' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(193,27): error C2838: 'y': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(194,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'z' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(194,27): error C2838: 'z': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(195,27): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'scalar' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(195,27): error C2838: 'scalar': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(197,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setX' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(197,26): error C2838: 'setX': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(198,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setY' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(198,26): error C2838: 'setY': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(199,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setZ' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(199,26): error C2838: 'setZ': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(200,26): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'setScalar' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(200,26): error C2838: 'setScalar': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(202,37): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'dotProduct' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(202,37): error C2838: 'dotProduct': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(207,33): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'inverted' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(207,33): error C2838: 'inverted': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(220,33): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override 'conjugated' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(220,33): error C2838: 'conjugated': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(225,34): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '+=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(225,34): error C2838: '+=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(234,34): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '-=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(234,34): error C2838: '-=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(243,34): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '*=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(243,34): error C2838: '*=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(253,1): error C2804: binary 'operator *' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(253,1): error C2333: 'QAbstract3DAxis::operator *': error in function declaration; skipping function body (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(268,34): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '*=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(268,34): error C2838: '*=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(274,34): error C3254: 'QAbstract3DAxis': class contains explicit override '/=' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(274,34): error C2838: '/=': illegal qualified name in member declaration (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(284,1): error C2804: binary 'operator +' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(284,1): error C2333: 'QAbstract3DAxis::operator +': error in function declaration; skipping function body (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(289,1): error C2804: binary 'operator -' has too many parameters (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(289,1): error C2333: 'QAbstract3DAxis::operator -': error in function declaration; skipping function body (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
1>C:\Qt\6.2.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui\qquaternion.h(289,1): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation (compiling source file src\mainwindow.cpp)
```

Example inside Qt Creator works fine using the same Qt 6.2.2. Inside Visual Studio I did add `datavisualization` module.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Possibly: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416418/define-nominmax-using-stdmin-max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416418/define-nominmax-using-stdmin-max)

Comment: Do you have `#include "windows.h"` in your code?

Comment: @drescherjm yes I do have it in one header doing windows-specific styling.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried to add `#define NOMINMAX` before include but it didn't help. Setting define in preprocessor setting in Visual Studio for some reason works (spewing warnings about its redefinition due to manual define statement)