# QML project gives nonsense errors then randomly works

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML project (QtQuick application) in Visual Studio 2022. I am using Visual Studio as I am integrating QML for UI in a larger project and I do not want to switch my dev environment. I have the Qt VS Tools extension and a Qt Widgets project works fine, this is only an issue with QtQuick.

Every time I run my application (using F5) I am greeted with a slew of errors than have nothing to do with my project as far as I can tell.

Here is the output log:

```
1>main.cpp
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(23,60): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(24,46): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(35,69): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,44): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,84): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(23,60): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(23,34): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(24,46): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(24,46): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(24,51): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(24,53): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(19,27): error C3615: constexpr function 'QJSNumberCoercion::isInteger' cannot result in a constant expression
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(19,27):
1>failure was caused by control reaching the end of a constexpr function
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(35,69): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(35,43): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(35,74): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(35,76): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(33,27): error C3615: constexpr function 'QJSNumberCoercion::isArrayIndex' cannot result in a constant expression
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(33,27):
1>failure was caused by control reaching the end of a constexpr function
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,44): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,18): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,84): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,84): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,89): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>C:\Qt\6.6.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtQml\qjsnumbercoercion.h(47,91): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')
1>Done building project "PROJECTNAME.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The log often says `(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')`, but there is nothing I can change in my `mail.cpp` file. Here is the file:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qt/qml/PROJECTNAME/main.qml")));

    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1; 

    return app.exec();
}
```

This is pretty much exactly what I was given when I made the project. I cannot understand how the errors have anything to do with this. Finally, if I just keep trying it will just work without me changing anything. Usually second or third time, but something it takes near then.

What could be a possible cause for this error? I cannot find anything only and I need a fix as it is a massive hindrance to developing my application.

Comment: Visual Studio breaks the `std::min` ad `std::max` functions.  [Your project needs to define `NOMINMAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416418/define-nominmax-using-stdmin-max).

Comment: The errors and warning themselves comes from the Qt system header files. The `(compiling source file 'Source/main.cpp')` message is just informational, saying that the errors and warnings were generated while building that file.

Comment: @DrewDormann I see. I found that as a fix to including windows.h which redefines the min and max macros as I understand. I figured since the problematic files use std::min and std::max this would not be the case. I see I was wrong. Thank you for this! Feel free to post this as an answer, I will gladly mark it correct!

Comment: That said, I would still love to know why it randomly worked sometimes without me changing a single line of code.

Comment: I am confused. Does your Qt code include `windows.h`?

Comment: @drescherjm Nope. That is why I didn't try the `#define NOMINMAX` fix. Perhaps Qt includes it somewhere internally? Also the problematic file uses std::min and std::max, not the macros. I guess it is as simple as Drew Dormann said, Visual Studio just breaks something.