# NOMINMAX with Visual Studio 2012 MFC project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I want to use `#define NOMINMAX` in my Visual Studio C++ project using MFC, so that I can use `std::min` and `std::max`. However, when I put this line in my stdafx.h, I get following compile error:

> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\GdiplusTypes.h(475): error C3861: 'min': identifier not found

I am not using GDI+ intentionally, this is something MFC must be doing. Can the issue be fixed somehow, either by removing the GDI+, or by adjusting it to compile?

Comment: There seems to be a similar question with an answer mentioning a workaround, however I do not understand the steps describing the workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914108/16673

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't work on Windows so I'm not used to dealing with this, and I'm not testing this, but I believe that answer is suggesting you do this:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <algorithm>
namespace Gdiplus
{
  using std::min;
  using std::max;
};
//... your other includes.
```

This will get the "proper" versions of `min` and `max`, and make them available without the `std::` prefix (which seems to be how it is used in the `GdiplusTypes.h` header).

Comment: This removes the compile error, however it brings min and max into the to global scope, which the answer specifically mentions as a bad thing. However, it helped me to make the sense of it. I have edited the code to achieve what was described in that answer.

Comment: @Suma See my answer for a solution that _doesn't_ bring min and max into the global scope.

Answer (score 5):

The winapi `min` and `max` are macros, so you can just `#undef` them after including the MFC or winapi headers:

```
#undef min
#undef max
```

Comment: And don't `#define NOMINMAX`.