# Syntax errors after including <Windows.h>

Tags: c++, windows, qt, bitmapimage

So, there is a library on the Internet to handle bitmap files: ["bitmap_image.hpp"](http://partow.net/programming/bitmap/). It seems nice and it works well for my project, until when I try to include "Windows.h" in my project as well. The compiler can't identify both the "bitmap_image" class and "POINT" structure which come from "bitmap_image.hpp" and "Windows.h" respectively.

I tried everything I know but the problem is still not solved. Also, when try to compile another project which includes ONLY *cstdio, bitmap_image.hpp* and *Windows.h*, it works.

I uses Qt and here are all the code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtDebug>
#include "bitmap_image.hpp"
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

double compare_bitmap(bitmap_image& large, bitmap_image& small, unsigned int top_left_x, unsigned int top_left_y)
{
    /*
    Purpose:
        compare two bitmaps and return the percentage of matched pixels

    Description:
        this function concerns the pixels in "large" only if it falls in this square--
        top-left:     (top_left_x, top_left_y)
        bottom-right: (top_left_x+small.width()-1, top_left_y+small.height()-1)

        while all pixels in "small" will be concerned

    Rules:
        "large" should not be smaller than "small" in either dimensions
        top_left_x should be ranged from 0 to (large.width()-small.width())
        top_left_y should be ranged from 0 to (large.height()-small.height())
    */

    if(large.width()<small.width() || large.height()<small.height()) return -1;
    if(top_left_x<0 || top_left_x>(large.width()-small.width()) || top_left_y<0 || top_left_y>(large.height()-small.height())) return -2;

    double pixel_count = 0;
    double matched_count = 0;

    for(unsigned int y=0; y<small.height(); ++y)
    {
        for(unsigned int x=0; x<small.width(); ++x)
        {
            if(large.get_pixel(top_left_x+x, top_left_y+y)==small.get_pixel(x,y)) ++matched_count;
            ++pixel_count;
        }
    }

    return matched_count/pixel_count;
}

bool identify_bitmap(bitmap_image& large, bitmap_image& small, POINT& result_point, double min_match_percent = 1.0)
{
    if(large.width()<small.width() || large.height()<small.height()) return false;

    unsigned int p_x, p_y;
    double match_percent = 0;

    for(unsigned int y=0; y<(large.height()-small.height()+1); ++y)
    {
        for(unsigned int x=0; x<(large.width()-small.width()+1); ++x)
        {
            double percent = compare_bitmap(large, small, x, y);
            if(percent>match_percent)
            {
                p_x = x;
                p_y = y;
                match_percent = percent;
            }
        }
    }

    if(match_percent<min_match_percent) return false;

    result_point.x = p_x;
    result_point.y = p_y;
    return true;
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    string s = "capture_2.bmp";
    bitmap_image image(s);

    if(!image) qDebug()<<"failed";
    else qDebug()<<"succeed";
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to show exactly the error messages from the compiler. Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` )

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186250/include-windows-h-causes-a-lot-of-syntax-errors

Answer (score 1):

Update: I just find the solution for myself. Sorry for the post.

Solution: [The first post to this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186250/include-windows-h-causes-a-lot-of-syntax-errors) stated that we can **`#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` just prior to `#include <Windows.h>`**

Although I don't fully understand the reasons...

Comment: The reason is that `<windows.h>` defines a big lot of macros. And macros respect no namespaces, they are effectively global, that's what is sometimes called _global namespace pollution_. The `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` trick prevents most of these nocive macros.

Comment: oic, global namespace pollution, interesting term. Thanks~