# SpriteBatch and SpriteFont (DirectXTK) throw an error (expected unqualified-id)

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I'm using `clang++` that links to `MSVC`.

I compiled shaders (`DirectXTK\Shaders`) and included `SpriteBatch` and `SpriteFont` in my source code.

If I include just the header files (`.h`), I get linking errors; if I include source files (`.cpp`; with or without `.h`), I get this:

```
SpriteBatch.cpp:532:27: error: expected unqualified-id
    size_t newSize = std::max(InitialQueueSize, mSpriteQueueArraySize * 2);
                          ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\shared\minwindef.h:193:29: note: expanded from macro 'max'
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

I tried to find the solution on the GitHub issues page of DirectXTK, on this website and on the web, but didn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows headers define a 'min' and 'max' macro that interacts poorly with `std::min`/`std::max` from `<algorithm>`.

In all my templates and tests, I define `NOMINMAX` before using `Windows.h` to avoid this problem. It's generally a better practice. If you still need to use a macro form while doing this, you can use `__min`/`_max`.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define NOMINMAX
#define NODRAWTEXT
#define NOGDI
#define NOBITMAP
#define NOMCX
#define NOSERVICE
#define NOHELP

#include <Windows.h>
```

See [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913922/possible-problems-with-nominmax-on-visual-c) and [this blog post](http://www.suodenjoki.dk/us/archive/2010/min-max.htm)

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue with min/max, but now I get linker errors that are coming from `SpriteBatch` and `SpriteFont` source files. The errors are about external symbols, such as `DirectX::BinaryReader`, `struct ID3D11RasterizerState`, etc. being referenced in functions, such as `DirectX::SpriteBatch::Impl::PrepareForRendering(void)` and `DirectX::SpriteFont::SpriteFont`. Those are unrelated to my code, since I commented out parts that are referring to my font implementation. Did I miss linking a specific static library?

Comment: Answering my question - yes, it seems like I also had to include `BufferHelpers`, `CommonStates`, `VertexTypes`, and `BinaryReader`. Maybe I miss something, but I don't understand why do I need to include those, since I already gave my compiler the include paths to these files.

Comment: Your program needs to link with the static library ``DirectXTK.lib`` to work. Take a look at ``CMakeLists.txt`` for build details if you are not using Visual Studio.

Comment: I was linking to `DirectXTK.lib` (since I was using texture functions), but it seems like that wasn't enough, and I grep'ed functions in the error list and included corresponding source files.